# group by follow by order by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to find out query in which group by is followed by order by.

My table is **resource_monitor**

```
id  |   server_ip   |    rdp_connection
1   |  192.168.1.45 |          9
2   |  192.168.1.46 |          12
3   |  192.168.1.45 |          8
4   |  192.168.1.45 |          4
5   |  192.168.1.46 |          3
```

I have user query

**select * from resource_monitor group by server_ip order by id desc**

This gives me result as

```
id  |   server_ip   |    rdp_connection
2   |  192.168.1.46 |          12
1   |  192.168.1.45 |          9
```

But I want all unique server_ip's last record

```
id  |   server_ip   |    rdp_connection
4   |  192.168.1.45 |          4
5   |  192.168.1.46 |          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with SubQuery as following

```
SELECT *
    FROM
      (SELECT *
       FROM resource_monitor
       ORDER BY id DESC) AS test
    GROUP BY test.server_ip
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to get first max(id) using sub-query and use it in where clause

```
 select * from resource_monitor where id in 
      (select max(id) from resource_monitor group by server_ip ) 
    order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

looking to you data sample seem you need the last value for each server_ip

```
select id, server_ip, rdp_connection
from resource_monitor
where ( id,server_ip ) in 
( select max(id) as id, server_ip from resource_monitor 
  group by server_ip )
  order by id desc
```